# Firebase Firestore get time difference between timestamp and now

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore and I got a field with type of timestamp which record the timestamp when document was stored in the database, and it worked perfectly.

And I want to get the time different between that timestamp and current timestamp (now). How can i do that

This is the sample document I stored in the database `2020-12-11T03:01:31.674Z`

[image]

Comment: That's not a timestamp type field.  That's a string field with a formatted timestamp value.  You're going to have to parse it into some format that you can use to compare the dates to each other mathematically.

Comment: thanh you so much, do you have any code sample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Doug Stevenson in the comments, the field in your Firestore is a String, not a Timestamp, so you will have to convert it before you can be operated by your code. You could do something like this:

```
const doc = db.collection('posts').doc(id).get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
       var data = doc.data();
       var createdAt = (new Date(data.first).getTime());
       var difference = Date.now() - createdAt;
       //this will be in milliseconds
       console.log(difference);
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```